# MongoDB on AIX Server

Tags: mongodb, aix

I am new to mongoDb. I am trying to install mongo Db on AIX server. Can someone suggest whether AIX supports MongoDb and specify which version, installation steps as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support AIX. You can see the supported platforms on the [download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are all expecting for a support of big endian (AIX/HP-UX...) for mongoDB. But, it is quite possible to install mongo on AIX... but really no simple! You have two options to do it :

- using SpiderMonkey and his JS engine (learn more about SpiderMonkey here: [spidermonkey](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/46419580374/mongodb-24-javascript-changes) )
- with this option at the install " --js-engine=none --server-js=off "  it allows you making MongoDB work in AIX.